# getting two divs to fill entire vertical space

Tags: html, space, fill

this seem like such a common problem, and I've spend a few hours trying to figure this out online..

Situation:

- I have 2 divs: div_header, div_content
- Whatever vertical space div_header does not occupy, I need div_content to fill the remaining space, as the size of the browser changes

Code:

```
<html>
<head> 
</head>

<body>

<div id = "div_header">             
</div>

<div id="div_content">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: #div_content 
{
min-height: 100%;
}

Answer (score 0):

Edit: misunderstood OP requirements:

Use the following CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#div_header {
  height: 100px;
}

#div_content
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Alex,
When I try that, the height becomes 100% of the original screen size. Since the div_header has some height to it (depending on content), the website becomes height of (div_header + 100% of original screen). Any ideas? Sincerely, Matt

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstood the question.  Will you know the height of the header in advance?  If so, there is a pure CSS solution.  Otherwise, you need JS to be cross-browser.

Comment: Alex, yes, I would know the height of the header in advance (in pixels). Do you have any ideas? Thanks for your time so far. Sincerely, Matt

Comment: I've edited to use absolute position and top/bottom to size.  To be honest, you might instead consider a different structure (header div _inside_ content div, which is 100% height and relatively positioned).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want JS solution or not. here's my try. On my screen if height of browsers dips below 400px then it shows scroll other wise it is okay.

```
<html>
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">

function heightDo()
{

var headerO = document.getElementById("div_header");
var contentO = document.getElementById("div_content");
//var docH = document.height;
var bodH = document.body.offsetHeight;
contentO.style.height = bodH - headerO.offsetHeight;
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
}
#div_header
{
height:auto;


}
#div_content { 


}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="heightDo()">

<div id="div_header">  
header           
<br/>
What do you say?
</div>

<div id="div_content">
content
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is the css version only

<html>
<head> 

<style type="text/css">
html, body {
}
#div_header
{
height:15%;
 
 
}
#div_content { 
height:85%;

}
div#wrapper
{
 height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="div_header">  
header           
<br/>
What do you say?
</div>

<div id="div_content">
content
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I don't know what's broke, but editing answer took aweful time without success

Comment: Anubhav, I'm going to give your javascript solution a shot. Will post back how it works. I tried the css solution, but I forgot to mention that the div_header must remain the same height as the size of the browser changes. Thanks for the time you've given me. Sincerely, Matt

Comment: Anubhav, the javascript is so close. I just need now div_content to expand as the browser changes size. Right now once it has been created, it remains the same size as the browser changes size. Thoughts? Sincerely, Matt